# Easily incorporate blog feed into site

Tags: wordpress

I built a site for a client not too long ago and built it fairly standard.  Now she has a Wordpress blog and would like an area on the main site to have links to the most recent blog posts.  Is there an easy way for me to pull a list of the most recent posts into this content area without having to chop the page up into a Wordpress template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to place the WP feed on the static site? Maybe [Developer's Guide - Google AJAX Feed API - Google Code](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/documentation/)

Answer (score 1):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feedlist

Comment: This looks like it's for pulling as RSS feed into Wordpress blog.  I'm looking to do the opposite.

We have site.com/index.html
And blog at site.com/blog

I want to pull in links to, say, the last 3 posts from site.com/blog and list them in the site.com/index.html sidebar.

Comment: Ah, I see. The direction wasn't clear from the question... :S

Answer (score 1):

I have a WordPress blog integrated into my hand-coded site. I use SimplePie to display my latest posts on my website's home page. I wrote a blog post about how to do this - [Displaying WordPress posts on a separate web page](http://blog.thelibzter.com/displaying-wordpress-posts-on-a-separate-web-page). Hopefully that will work for you as well. Let me know if you need more information or help.